# What is the best way to provide a default CSS style, that gets overridden by jQuery UI, for No Script scenarios?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, progressive-enhancement, noscript

For example: I have a pager `<< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 >>` in my page where every navigation element is a normal Html link. For modern browsers with JS enabled, I would like to beautify them with [jQuery's .button()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/). But I would like to have something for NoScript scenario. Obviously I should add some CSS styling for the links, but how do I know the custom CSS won't screw up jQuery's styling?

Is this a needless concern? Does jQuery provide some function to clear out any previous styling for element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery UI's own stylesheet. Take a look at their [documentation of the framework](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API)--its pretty straight forward.

Among the many pro's of using jQuery UI's CSS framework are: robust and cross-browser compatible CSS. A solid stream of bugfixes (if any). And if you decide to change the color scheme of your application; all you need to do is replace the stylesheet, with a new [theme-rolled](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) one, or one of the standard themes that comes bundled with jQuery UI.

Needless to say; jQuery UI can't override/frack up it's own CSS. And you will get a pager that looks the same with and without JavaScript enabled.

Tip: If you haven't got the time to read through the jQuery UI CSS framework documentation; use [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com) (Mozilla FireFox add-on) to inspect the HTML generated by jQuery UI and apply it to your no-script-markup.

**Update**

Just inspected a link made into a button. Here's the markup generated by jQuery UI's buttton plug-in:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text">An anchor</span>
</a>
```

Comment: You have no idea how much I like this solution. Domo arigatou!

Comment: However, there is a problem. jQuery doesn't check whether that span already exists and adds another one.

Comment: A simple work-around would be to remove the span elements, and then call `.button()` on the a-elements: `$("a").each(function () { var that = $(this); var s = $("span", that); var v = s.val(); s.remove(); that.html(v).button() });`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to apply a class to the pager to be used in the NoScript scenario, and simply remove that class using JavaScript after setting up your buttons.

Comment: Simple and elegant! However I like roosteronacid's answer more in my scenario. Have an upboat!